# How to install g++ 4.9 on Debian Wheezy armel?

Tags: c++11, g++, arm, debian, gcc4.9

My Debian 7 armel embedded system currently has g++ 4.6, and I'd like to upgrade to g++ 4.9 to use new C++11 features.  How do I do that?

My current sources.list contents is:

```
    deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
    deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
    deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy main non-free
    deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy main non-free
```

A simple apt-get install of the package does not work:

```
    root@arm:~#  apt-get install g++-4.9
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package g++-4.9
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-4.9'
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install g++-4.9`?

Comment: You may need `jessie` for that.

Comment: A simple apt-get install does not work, alas.

Comment: You might want to try to add the "testing" repository to your sources.list: `deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ testing contrib main` (you could add the `non-free` subbranch as well, I'm pretty sure this isn't needed for gcc though).

Comment: Look at the [Debian package search](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gcc-4.9), there is no gcc-4.9 for *wheezy*.  You can get [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) and build your own compiler.  Otherwise, someone needs to point you to a '.deb' for 4.9; it may exist some time in the future.

Comment: Yes I agree and I think that crosstool-ng is only the right solution for embedded system.

Answer (score 17):

Another workaround could be to install the g++ 4.9 packages from "Jessie", according to [this blog post](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/13/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-14-programs/). Briefly, you would have to tell APT to use the Jessie repos while you are installing the new G++. First bring the current Wheezy up-to-date:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then do a backup :-) and edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` so that you replace the string `"wheezy"` with `"jessie"`:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.WHEEZY
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now update the package list and install the 4.9 version of GCC/G++:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

After this revert to the "original" package list:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.WHEEZY /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

This leaves the original GCC,G++ in place. If you wish to compile with the 4.9 version, then either set the `CC` and `CXX` env vars accordingly or invoke the compilers as `gcc-4.9` or `g++-4.9` explicitly.

Comment: Three people have indicated that this was a useful post but nobody claimed it works.  I followed the steps above and it worked.  Thank you for this.

Comment: I will also add that it works, and was essential to get Page Speed Module running on Debian 7 wheezy. Thanks!

Comment: This also worked for me to get Stretch's `gcc-6.3` on Wheezy. I did the above with the following line in my `sources.list` file: `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free contrib`. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

Probably-required: `packaging-dev`, `ubuntu-dev-tools`

#### Set up pbuilder

(this lets you build a package in a chroot without polluting your system with build-dependency packages)

```
sudo pbuilder create
```

if you want to build for a specific distribution, (pbuilder uses the build system release in a chroot) you can use pbuilder-dist [precise/oneric/trusy/etc...] create

#### Get debian source

```
pull-debian-source gcc-4.9 [4.9.0-6]
```

specific debian revision is optional, but can be useful if you want to pull experimental/unstable/testing/stable revisions
you can also pull from specific ubuntu distros by adding them to sources.list as a deb-src and using sudo apt-get src

#### Build Package

```
sudo pbuilder build gcc-4.9_4.9.0-6.dsc
```

In the files downloaded there is a .dsc file, for the most recent gcc it is gcc-4.9_4.9.0-6.dsc which is a package descriptor file. .orig.tar.[gz/xz] is the source tarball.

#### Create local Apt-repository

```
mkdir /convenient/place/for/repo
cp /var/cache/pbuilder/result/* /path/to/repo
cd /path/to/repo
apt-ftp archive packages . > Packages
sudo echo "deb [trusted=yes] file:/local/repo/Packages ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcc-repo.list`
```

Note you can also do this step with .debs downloaded from anywhere (skip step 1-3)

#### Install

```
apt-get update; apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

Comment: Wont this just build the package in a new environment from a later release? Seems no different to downloading from jessie.

Comment: These instructions worked fine for me, but just a warning for anyone who wants to follow these steps: building gcc/g++ takes a long time. The downloads take a while, and the compile itself takes a while. So don't do this if you're in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the jessie packages, it would be better to check to see if it's been back-ported to wheezy.  Add this to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

`deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main`

and do an `apt-get update` and see if you can install it then.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [gcc-4.9-backport](https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/gcc-4.9-backport) now.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-backport
```