# Arm toolchain and associated runtime

Tags: c++, linux

I am attempting to port an application to an arm processor and have run into a roadblock.  I don't get to change the source code and it uses a feature that is not available in the arm runtime on the arm host.  I get the message on the arm host:

/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by MyDaemon);

I ran
strings libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI and got the list with the last element as CXXABI_1.3.6.

Can I simply replace the toolchain/runtime on the arm machine or do I have to worry about other programs that link to it and will not run any longer?

g++ --version gives (Debian 4.6.3-14) 4.6.3

so maybe I can use a 4.9 toolchain and runtime?

The issue with that answer is that when the different libstdc++ is loaded it reports.

GLIBC_2.17 not found

The problem is that the environment on the machine where the application is compiled is different from the environment where the application is run and would like to know where to read to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [version \`CXXABI\_1.3.8' not found (required by ...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494103/version-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found-required-by)

Comment: Awesome recursive duplicate ;) Please use search before posting questions.

Comment: This is really a duplicate of  [How to install g++ 4.9 on Debian Wheezy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147363/how-to-install-g-4-9-on-debian-wheezy-armel)